# About the definition of amenable group.

Tags: group-theory

An amenable group is at most contable group $G$ for which exist a sequence $\{F_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of finite sets such that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|(g\cdot F_n)\triangle F_n|}{|F_n|}=0 $$
for every $g\in G$.

There is something that I am not understanding about this definition. The "almost trvial" example is $\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the sequence of sets of the form $[-N,N]=\{-N,-N+1,...,N-1, N\}$.

I tried to prove that indeed this sequence shows that $\mathbb{Z}$ is amenable.

But if we do the calculation $[-N,N]\triangle [-N+a,N+a]|=|[-N,N]\cup [-N+a,N+a]|=4N$ for every $a$ big enough and $|[-N,N]|=2N$ but this implies that

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|[-N,N]\cup [-N+a,N+a]|}{|[-N,N]|}=2 $$

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You say blah blah blah "for every $a$ big enough". That's irrelevant. You should _fix_ $a$ and let $N$ tend to infinity, not the other way around.

Comment: @TsemoAristide: there are probably hundred different and equivalent conditions for amenability :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set $F_N := [-N, N]$, then for big enough $N$ you will have that $a F_N \Delta F_N$ has $2 |a|$ elements ($a$ is fixed!!), while $F_N$ has *always* $2N + 1$ elements (don't forget to count $0$). So for $N \to \infty$ this goes to $0$ as desired.

Comment: It was an extremely silly question. Thanks for answer it. Know I can continue.